# SAML: Is SignatureValue and X509Certificate reusable?

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am new to SAML and I've recently been asked to implement an SSO SP using Spring Security SAML Extension.

I was able to implement the entire SSO Flow and it seems to be working correctly but I just want to understand how secure SAML is.

Can attackers sniff the SAML Response, take out the signatureValue and public certificate and reuse them to make another SSO request? (This is without considering the other assertion attributes like time, etc)

I hope someone can enlighten me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need the private key in order to generate a new signature. The public key is used for verification, the private key for signature generation. I would suggest reading one of many articles on explaining PKI and how it works that are available on internet. There are other forms of attack that your certificate might suggest are possible, so you could encrypt the response or even use out-of-bounds SAML profile such as artifact resolution. Of course this is all dependent on your IdP and whether or not it supports it.